# Check location of explicit permissions for a given user

Tags: permissions

In SharePoint 2010, when inheritence is broken for a subsite and a user is explicitly given permissions to that subsite, they then show up under http://sharepoint/sites/sitecollection/_layouts/user.aspx as a user with limited access.

I would like to be able to find out what site(s) these users have been given explicit access to within the site collection.  The "Check Permissions" option will show what groups give them permissions, but not the (sub)sites that those permissions apply to.

Is there a way to see what sites a given user has been given explicit access to?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried writing something in Powershell?

Gary Lapointe wrote a great blog post on how to do this with Powershell

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/04/discovering-who-has-access-to-sharepoint-2010-securable-objects/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the article "**Check User Permissions Programmatically in SharePoint 2010**"

at http://tad.co.in/?p=748

Answer (score 0):

Third party tools like Deliverpoint from Lightning Tools can help with this.  I'm sure DocAve and Axceler have offerings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching SUSHI in CodePlex. Its a good tool to fetch a data regarding to permission in a site