# Viewing all permissions for a user or AD Group in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: permissions, security

[Similar to this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11862/check-location-of-explicit-permissions-for-a-given-user) is there a similar way to look up permissions for a given user or AD Group?  SharePoint 2007 really doesn't work in PowerShell and the Internet didn't yield much here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharePoint SUSHI](http://sushi.codeplex.com/) (SharePoint Utility with a Smart, Helpful Interface) is a free administrative tool for SharePoint that among other tasks, will list the permissions a user or AD group has within an entire site collection (the screenshot on the main page shows this functionality).

Disclosure: I have no affiliation with SUSHI but I have used it specifically to find out permissions for some users.

Answer (score 2):

You can get information via PowerShell in MOSS 2007. The script from this site will traverse a site and give you groups and permissions.

To quote form the site, it will:

Recursively crawl a site or entire web application within SharePoint
Enumerate permissions assigned to a SharePoint site Detail the
SharePoint users assigned to a SharePoint group Determine if an
Active Directory group is a member of a SharePoint group Detail the Active Directory users who are members of an Active Directory group
Search for a specific user’s permissions on a SharePoint site

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/04/24/the-power-of-powershell-and-sharepoint-enumerating-sharepoint-permissions-and.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[The SharePoint Admin Toolkit](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2009/08/27/3277616.aspx) has some features that help tracking down user permissions within the SharePoint interface.  We have it installed and it definitely helps track down why people might get access denied errors due to permissions and comparing permission sets.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout [SharePoint Permissions Manager](http://permissionsmanager.codeplex.com/) which gives a quick view of all the permissions for the group/user within the site.

Comment: Negative, this tool does not do AD Users or groups only SharePoint groups, used already

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I believed, the users and AD group permissions you are talking about, are the users and groups from AD directly added into your SharePoint site within SharePoint groups. Moreover the link, you provided was speaking about permissions in site and site collections. So I came to that conclusion. Anyway, good to know, you got the right solution.